# Mysql full text search boolean mode order by relevancy not order I am seeking (Phrase matching)

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have the query below and the relevancy ranking seems to be off.

It ranks

```
iPhone 5C Used Verizon 8GB 58165 White
```

higher than

```
iPhone 8 Front Camera Flex
```

What it seems to be doing is ranking how many times it counts the words in the search phase. I want to give higher relevancy if the words are next to each other (as shown above)

```
SELECT phppos_items.name, MATCH (phppos_items.name) AGAINST ('iphone 8*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as rel 
FROM phppos_items
WHERE MATCH (phppos_items.name) AGAINST ('iphone 8*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY `rel` DESC;
```

Results (Too large to paste)

https://gist.github.com/blasto333/d8f8fe470cc1cfb1f959922ea77f8134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let`s first analyze the condition that you use and also sort by:

```
MATCH (phppos_items.name) AGAINST ('iphone 8*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

According to [Mysql Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html), you are matching any texts that contain **ANY** of the words:

- iphone
- 8

Meaning any texts that have **iphone**  **OR** **8** are matched.

What you want is to match "**iphone 8**" as a string with priority over both "iphone" or "8*".

To achieve this:

- Add "iphone 8*" as a string to match
- use the ***> <*** operators
- and give it a **priority** over both "iphone" and "8*"

Change the sql query to:

```
AGAINST ('>"iphone 8*" >iphone <8*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

in the select statement

meaning that it gives **priority to exact iphone 8* and iphone** over **8***.